# Why does C++'s complex class use getters and setters?

Tags: c++, getter-setter

Why does the C++ complex class use functions to modify the real and imaginary parts?  Wouldn't public member variables work just as well without having to deal with getters and setters?  All that's been hidden is the private name of the real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simple reason for this is that it allows the implementation to change over time, even if it may not actually change often (if ever).  If you have a class and you're modifying its instance variables, you're now dependent on those instance variables existing instead of having a public interface that could remain the same without changing (despite the implementation changing, for example with platform-dependent code).

Femaref's answer is also correct – the methods can allow for certain logic to occur that might be necessary.  Without that, you might not be getting the correct data from the object.

Comment: In general this is the best practice, however in the case of `std::complex` the "internal implementation change" motivation is now a little weak, since the C++0x standard actually mandates the internal structure of the class.

Comment: @Matteo Didn't know that, but I haven't really kept up on C++0x's development either.  That said, I wouldn't rule out the possibility that some implementations just won't completely conform to the standard (though why they wouldn't conform with `std::complex` in particular is beyond me).

Comment: In general the concept of not exposing the member variables is a good idea. But complex is so well defined that the extra level of indirection seems to defeat the purpose of an easy to use object. To me complex is a property bag.

Comment: Agreed.  Although getters and setters are a good practice, for POD types and extremely simple classes like std::complex I feel they are unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

Probably because there is additional logic in the methods, which is not possible with public member variables.